# Keep div horizontally centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap well and inside that well there is a div with elements named "parent". Parents are floating left to each other. If div is big enough to fit 4 parents it will fit 4 parents in a row and others in second and so on, if it is big enough to fit three it will fit three in one row ...(size depends on the screen width). The problem appears when div is big for 3 and a half parents or 4 and 20px or something like that. Then the place left is filled with margin as you can see on picture:

[image: Margin on right]

How could I keep div with parents horizontally centered inside bootstrap well, so there will never be unevenly distributed margin. Margin should be always the same on left and right side. The code is here (ignore the clear div, it just help with the float of parents, so the well stretches with parents):

```css
/* Some CSS to make the result easier to follow */
.parent {
  background-color: white;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="well" style="padding: 2em 0;">
  <div class="profile-exams">
    <div class="parent" style="float: left; width: 200px" margin="10px;">parent div </div>
    <div class="parent" style="float: left; width: 200px" margin="10px;">parent div </div>
    <div class="clear" style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I can't set static width of "profile-exams", as it varies if there are 2, 3 or 5 boxes inside it. But if I can't define the width, it wouldn't center.

Comment: Use the Bootstrap grid columns

Comment: how would i do it with grid columns? @ZimSystem

Comment: @csserrs Can I have a jsfiddle with the code used to produce the output in the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but here it is:

```css
.profile-exams {
  text-align: center;
}
.parent {
  text-align: left;
/* These lines aren't necessary, but just to make the result easier to follow */
  background-color: white;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="well" style="padding: 2em 0;">
  <div class="profile-exams">
    <div class="parent" style="display: inline-block; width: 200px" margin="10px;">parent div </div>
    <div class="parent" style="display: inline-block; width: 200px" margin="10px;">parent div </div>
    <div class="clear" style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/AquatuzMagnus/pen/XRLQrx)

Comment: thank you for your response but text-align center doesnt seem to do the trick.. i would post snippet, but the website is dynamic and i would have to edit it for long time as it contains many django variables

Comment: Ok, I'll try and fix that

Comment: @csserrs In what way does text-align center not work?

Comment: it just doesnt have any effect on the divs inside

Comment: possibly because of floating divs inside?

Comment: @csserrs Yes, it's because of floating divs. Remove the float property, and replace it with `display: inline-block;` and it'll work

Comment: @csserrs Pleasure!